# How to play .m3u playlist on iOS, given its URL?

Tags: ios, playlist, url

When clicking on a URL for an M3U playlist on an iPhone, it opens in Safari as a blank, gray webpage, and no audio plays.

How can I play an M3U playlist on an iPhone, given the URL to the playlist? Does Apple have a URL scheme where I can make a URL that will tell the phone to open the playlist up in iTunes?

Comment: Seems to be an iOS limit and I am looking for a workaround too. To reproduce the error and get a better help from the Stack: I created an example player here https://biker-elegant.github.io/Stackoverflow-m3u/static_files/play.m3u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download following app; add your m3u list to app content; watch what you want :)

https://itunes.apple.com/tr/app/iptv-m3u-player-ip-television/id1368623943?l=tr&mt=8

Comment: Can you add some details about what the app does? And maybe provide a link to the english version of the page :-)

Comment: Think you have a URL that includes one or more channels.
That URL meaned m3u playlist. You can buy or you can get it from someone else. 

Actually ios does not provide to open your m3u playlist. You need an app for open and watch TV channels.
The app that following link provide to open the URL and watch your chanells in your m3u playlist.
You can watch channels from your iphone or ipad where you want.

App has english language support with one button.

https://itunes.apple.com/tr/app/iptv-m3u-player-ip-television/id1368623943?l=tr&mt=8

Comment: @patrix ? what do you think about explanation of the app ? do you think is it enough ?

Comment: Please edit your answer with additional information, don't just add a comment.